# Why is "isWriteable" returning false using QSerialport?

Tags: qt, ubuntu, serial-port

I have a working program in QT creator on my mac that can write out an FTDI cable using QSerialport.  However when I run the exact same program on ubuntu in QT creator the "isWriteable" bool returns false.  All other aspects of the program run the same on mac and ubuntu. (the ftdi driver is installed on ubuntu)

Here is the section of code that keeps returning false:

```
if(FTDI->isWritable())
{
    FTDI->putChar(gyroX);
}
```

Does anyone know what would cause this?

Comment: You could check the QSerialPort::error() function and see what it returns. If it doesn't return QSerialPort::NoError, something is wrong. Perhaps a permission or general device error?

Answer (score 0):

The Docs state for isWritable():

...

This is a convenience function which checks if the OpenMode of the device contains the `WriteOnly` flag.

See also `openMode()` ...

So do you open your device with the right flags ? Your should open it either with `WriteOnly` or `ReadWrite` (which contains WriteOnly) or something else which contains `WriteOnly`.